# MOSFET Driver Stress

Tags: mosfet, motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am using an Allegro Microsystems A4935 3-phase MOSFET driver in a brushless speed controller. I recently got the motor spinning, but when I began increasing the voltage, my commutation started to become jerky, for reasons I suspect to be in software.

What I'm confused about is that, when this happens, both my MOSFETs and MOSFET driver heat up. At one point I released the magic smoke in the driver, and eventually the VBB trace (high voltage, supply for gate driver circuitry) going into the MOSFET driver even burned and broke! I understand that whenever the motor gets stuck, it causes large amounts of current through the MOSFETs, but why does this cause the MOSFET driver to heat up also?

The resistors I have at the gates of my IRFS7530 MOSFETs are 4.7Ω, and I'm driving the PWM at 25kHz. The driver only gets a little warm at no load driving the capacitance of the MOSFETs. My question is, **what causes this stress on the driver when there is a load? Why does sudden high current flowing through the MOSFETs cause the MOSFET driver to need lots of current? Isn't the only load on the driver due to charging the gates, which is independent of the current through the MOSFETs?**

Here is the schematic for the relevant part of the circuit:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Possibly because when the MOSFETs burn up they fail short including the gate, shorting the output of the driver? Does it have short-circuit protection? I haven't look at its datasheet...

Comment: Actually it does have such "ESF Pin This pin (Enable Stop on Fault) determines the action taken when a short circuit or overtemperature fault is detected", but are you using it?

Comment: The MOSFETs aren't the ones failing though. They only get warm under the high current because of their high current rating.

Comment: I see, I misread that part.

Comment: I'm wondering if this has anything to do with transients or "inductive kickback" during switching, but I don't really understand this concept. If someone could explain that would be great!

Comment: So did you actually burn the Vdd or the Vbb trace (i.e. the one that goes up to 50V)? Because the latter powers the actual MOSFET drivers, the former is only for the chip's logic.

Comment: "inductive kickback" would kill the MOSFETs not the driver.

Comment: Perhaps a dead time is too short. With STM32 you can set it in the PWM register, while in Arduino I think there is no such option. What drives the chip?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: That driver IC is protected by default against that. You have to disable it via the CCEN pin... "This input provides an override to allow both the highside
and the low-side external FETs of any phase to be active at
the same time, enabling cross-conduction. As an extra level of
safety, cross-conduction can only occur when RDEAD is tied to
AGND and CCEN is set high. If the CCEN input is inadvertently
disconnected from the controller, an internal pull-down resistor
ensures that the outputs revert to a safe condition".

Comment: I think given the complexity of this IC, we'd need to see schematic or at least a description of how you connected all the relevant control pins.

Comment: The trace that burned was the VBB (high voltage) trace. I'm using a Teensy 3.0 to control PWM, and it has dead time generation capability. I don't think shoot-through is the problem because it is perfectly fine with no motor connected. I will attach a schematic soon.

Comment: I have attached my schematic. But my main question is mostly a conceptual one: why does load on the MOSFETs cause increased load on the driver? Isn't the only load on the driver due to driving the gates?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to monitor the xHI and xLO signals getting inside A4935, and also the respective Gate output from the A4935, using oscilloscope. Sometimes, due to switching of large current, there is a lot of EMI noise that penetrates in these small signals. And false trigger your MOSFET. Resulting in occasional Short-circuit condition.

I would also suggest to add 10K register between every MOSFET's Gate and Source.